# As we create view in mysql, can we do it in magento 2.1?? if yes, how to do it

Tags: magento-2.1, php, database

want to create an view in magento 2.1.7. As we do create in mysql, how to do it?? want to do it progmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can find more info about view here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html

But I do not see the sense to create view, you can create tempopary table using

```
Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql
```

Comment: can you tell me how to create tempopary tables in magento ?? if u share any link or any sample modules it would be more helpful